# Can a sensor have multiple I2C addresses?

Tags: i2c

So I'm having a weird issue with a TCA9548A multiplexer. When I run the scanning code given on the adafruit website, I get the following result:

TCAScanner ready!
TCA Port #0
TCA Port #1
TCA Port #2
Found I2C 0x0
Found I2C 0x44
TCA Port #3
TCA Port #4
TCA Port #5
TCA Port #6
TCA Port #7

done

And I suppose my question is, how is it possible that a device has two I2C addresses? I know for certain the address should be 0x44 but what does the 0x0 mean? and equally bizarre is that that sensor doesn't output numerical values when called. The sensor works perfectly when connected directly to an Arduino Mega 2560, but I can't get it to function with the multiplexer.

Comment: You are right that there's something wrong here. 0x0 is not a valid address for an I2C device. Maybe you should share the code that you use to do the scan.

Comment: Of course a device can have multiple addresses, theoretically. It's just a matter of comparing the received address with expected addresses, and acknowledging if one of them matches. Think about a microcontroller emulating multiple I²C chips. -- However, I don't think that a single chip exists that works like this. -- 0x00 belongs to [the reserved addresses](https://i2cdevices.org/addresses).

Comment: Can you link to the scanning code? The address 0x00 is the general call address. You can address every device on the bus with it (only master write, no master read transaction). Often these scanning codes only check for the acknowledgement after the address byte. For the general call address the protocol states that the devices on the bus all can acknowledge when receive a general call transaction. So seeing the address 0x00 does not by itself mean that something is wrong. And the [standard I2C scanner](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/) doesn't even use 0x00 as address.

Comment: Some people consider I2C devices' read- and write-header as two separate addresses. I2C addresses are usually 7-bit plus one read/write bit. If all those 256 addresses are scanned, a device would acknowledge on 2 addresses.